# How do you translate "Tempesta ti parendum" in english?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

What´s the deep meaning of this sentence?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Where is this sentence from? Context makes a big difference in deciphering a sentence. (Also, I recommend registering your account so that you get proper access to your question, including the ability to edit it.)

Answer (score 5):

Note it is probably *Tempestati parendum* (without the space before *ti*). Literally it means: The weather/season/storm must be obeyed. The grammatical construction (gerund+dative) is similar to an example given in [A&G](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/gerund-and-gerundive):

> Lēgibus pārendum est. The laws must be obeyed.

It is hard to comment on "deep meaning" of this motto, as this can be adapted for slightly different usages; the context is important. At any case a natural interpretation is that one should yield to higher powers and not to fight them.

In [Speculum Imaginum Veritatis Occultae](http://mateo.uni-mannheim.de/camenaref/masen/masen6/Masen_speculum_2.html) it indeed seems to be the suggested meaning:

> Id est, voluntati divinae parendum, et fortunae nimis iniquae concedendum. (we must obey to the divine will, and yield to the exceedingly-unjust fortune.)